# How to update the repository of the current project on github?

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

I have uploaded my project on github using intellij IDE but I need to know how to update the uploaded repository on github when I add new code ?

Answer (score 3):

"Adding new code" into your Git repository (your local repository, at first) is made by "making a commit". Full details about this : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Then, after one or more commits, if you want to upload your changes to your remote repository (the one at GitHub), you'll have to "push" your changes : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

For details and examples on using Git (because this goes far beyond a Q&A site thread), please have a look at my [Git beginner's guide](http://doc.callmematthi.eu/git.html#gitBeginnersGuide)

Answer (score 1):

The question does not look IntelliJ-specific.

To update the code on GitHub you need to commit changes to your local git repository and push the changes to GitHub. See https://help.github.com/en/articles/pushing-to-a-remote

Check the docs to see how exactly one commits and pushes in IntelliJ.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html